# How can I redefine the toolbar style for all my activities globally?

Tags: android, styling, android-appcompat

I have a AppCompat21 Appbar/Toolbar in almost all of my Activities. All activities layout files have the following in common:

```
<!-- material design actionbar & toolbar -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

so instead of having to add these attributes all the time:

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
 app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
```

I'm trying to find out how to redefine the appbar/toolbar look and feel in a global fashion within my app so I don't need this piece of redundant code everywhere.

Is this even possible? I have done it for the button style, but I can't get my head around this one...

Answer (score 3):

You can create a layout resource file containing your toolbar, named `toolbar`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
/>
```

and in your activities you can just simply do

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/toolbar">
```

Comment: I know this works, but part of my question is how to redefine the toolbar look and feel by using theme/style without having to put style="xyz" inside the tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Blank Activity project in Android Studio it creates a styles.xml that includes the following. I think the last 2 lines accomplish what you want at the theme level:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```